# Is the allocated number of CPUs freed to the host machine when I pause the virtual machine?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

In [KVM virt-manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/VirtManager), is the allocated number of CPUs released from the VM to the host machine if I pause the virtual machine?

[image]

If the allocated CPUs are released when I pause the virtual machine, I can then allocate a higher number of CPUs since I only tend to work with either the VM or the host machine, not both, at a time. So when I work with the VM it gets a high number of CPUs and when I pause the VM and work with the host machine it has a high number of CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual managers such as KVM and VirtualBox do not dedicate hardware to the virtual machines they manage, but instead manage limits. The actual management and utilisation of the hardware is controlled by the host operating system. This means that if your host has 12 threads available and six are allocated to a mostly-idle virtual machine, the host can still use most of the 12 threads.

So, to answer your question, when a virtual machine is paused, it consumes zero hardware resources (CPU/RAM/IO) until it is resumed.

You can read more about how `virt-manager` operates and how you can tweak it [on RedHat's Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/index). While the documentation is put out by RedHat, the fundamentals and operation are the same across the distributions.

Hope this answers your question.